# Open Android´s settings menu with code

Tags: android

Somebody knows how can I open Android´s Settings screen with code? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure but, maybe this help you:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);           
            startActivity(intent);
```